# AS3: SetChildIndex not working

Tags: actionscript-3, indexing, box2d

I'm working with the QuickBox2D library, and I'm trying to move one object to the bottom of the stage.

But it's not working, QuickBox2D doesn't seem to recognize it.

```
Call to a possibly undefined method setChildIndex through a reference with static type com.actionsnippet.qbox:QuickBox2D.
```

**Object:**

```
        var gameBall:QuickObject;
```

**ChildIndex**

```
        sim.setChildIndex(gameBall, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QuickBox2D](http://actionsnippet.com/qb2d/docs/html/index.html) class inherits from [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html), not [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) where **setChildIndex** is defined. I don't see a way to handle z-indicies in the QuickBox2D system, which actually makes sense to me because objects shouldn't overlap in a physical system.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at [`setChildIndex()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)

- It's a method defined by `DisplayObjectContainer`.
- Its first argument must be of type `DisplayObject`.

Currently, you're trying to:

1. Call `setChildIndex()` from an instance of `QuickBox2D` (not a `DisplayObjectContainer`).
2. Pass another instance of `QuickBox2D` as the first agument (which needs to be a `DisplayObject`).